# Convert Hourly Data To Half Hourly In Excel

Tags: excel

I can find a few solutions in converting half hourly data to hourly but not the other way round.

I have some data that is hourly:

```
21/11/2014 13:00    5
21/11/2014 14:00    16
21/11/2014 15:00    18
21/11/2014 16:00    3
21/11/2014 17:00    10
```

I would like to average this out as 30 minute data by dividing the hourly data by 2 and duplicating the rows as such:

```
21/11/2014 12:30    2.5
21/11/2014 13:00    2.5
21/11/2014 13:30    8
21/11/2014 14:00    8
21/11/2014 14:30    9
21/11/2014 15:00    9
21/11/2014 15:30    1.5
21/11/2014 16:00    1.5
21/11/2014 16:30    5
21/11/2014 17:00    5
```

I can't seem to work out what formula to use so that I can copy it down for the 9 months worth of data I have. The date is in column A and data in Column B.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

David

Comment: Use the INDEX function.  For the `Row` parameter, you need a function that will increase by `1` for every two rows as you fill it down.  So something like `INT(ROWS($1:1)/2)`.  For the Time column, you would add 30 minutes every other row; and for the Value column, you would divide by 2.  You can do that by testing for `ODD` or `EVEN` depending on how your data is set up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ron. I can work out the timestamp but am still struggling with splitting the data. If the first data value is in B1 and the split values should be in C1 and C2 - what should the formula be?

Comment: As I wrote, you can use the `INDEX` function. The `array` argument would be the range that includes all of your dates and values. Set up the parameter for the `row` argument similar to what I posted above (you may need to change it to something like `INT((ROWS$1:1)-1/2)+1`, and you will see how it returns what you require.  Post what you've done as an edit to your original post.

Comment: Is this accurate if you assume 50% happens in the first half hour and 50% in the second? It doesn't sound right to me - the results will be misleading if you do this in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot showing the formula in C1 as an example.  You should be able to work out the rest:

[image]